# NSTouchBar: How to replace "Esc" with "Done" button

Tags: cocoa, nstouchbar

How is AddressBook app presenting a Done instead of the Esc like the screenshot?

[image: AddressBook touch bar]

The documentation states that the System Provided button depends on the context. How do I define that context?

Answer (score -1):

Found it. You need to use an NSPopoverTouchBarItem. Set it to not show the close button, and add one yourself.

Comment: Yes, your solution is also working but I strongly believe that there must be a better solution for this, then hacking it with Popover. Maybe at this time it is just not possible, but later on Apple may release some additional API.